# OutOfMemoryException when using Xdocument Writeto xmlwriter

Tags: c#, xml, linq, out-of-memory, linq-to-xml

I am trying to write a big XDocument to StringBuilder using XmlWriter & TextWriter and I get the below OOM exception. I get this error for a specific big Xdocument. Appreciate any guidance and help to resolve this.

```
Error Message: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

Stack Trace:
  at System.GC.AllocateNewArray(IntPtr typeHandle, Int32 length, GC_ALLOC_FLAGS flags)
  at System.GC.<AllocateUninitializedArray>g__AllocateNewUninitializedArray|66_0[T](Int32 length, Boolean pinned)
  at System.Text.StringBuilder.ExpandByABlock(Int32 minBlockCharCount)
  at System.Text.StringBuilder.Append(Char* value, Int32 valueCount)
  at System.Text.StringBuilder.Append(Char[] value, Int32 startIndex, Int32 charCount)
  at System.IO.StringWriter.Write(Char[] buffer, Int32 index, Int32 count)
  at System.Xml.XmlEncodedRawTextWriter.FlushBuffer()
  at System.Xml.XmlEncodedRawTextWriter.WriteElementTextBlock(Char* pSrc, Char* pSrcEnd)
  at System.Xml.XmlEncodedRawTextWriter.WriteString(String text)
  at System.Xml.XmlEncodedRawTextWriterIndent.WriteString(String text)
  at System.Xml.XmlWellFormedWriter.WriteString(String text)
  at System.Xml.Linq.ElementWriter.WriteElement(XElement e)
  at System.Xml.Linq.XElement.WriteTo(XmlWriter writer)
  at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.WriteContentTo(XmlWriter writer)
  at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.WriteTo(XmlWriter writer)
```

Below is my code snippet

```
public StringBuilder ToXml()
{
    StringBuilder xmlStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    using (TextWriter textWriter = new Utf8StringWriter(xmlStringBuilder))
    using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(textWriter, new XmlWriterSettings() { Indent = true }))
    {
        this.ToXDocument().WriteTo(xmlWriter);
    }
    
    return xmlStringBuilder;
}
```

Comment: The problem seems clear -- you are running out of memory appending to a `StringBuilder`.  The solution would appear to be to not do that, and instead write directly to a file or response stream.  There's not enough information in the question to give more guidance than that.  Also, what does `this.ToXDocument()` do?  Could you serialize `this` directly without the intermediate `XDocument`?

Comment: Why use string builder.  You can use doc.ToString() or ele.ToString().